# I'm using SpreadSheetGear to create a 3D Pie chart. How do I change the Y-rotation value?

Tags: excel, charts, 3d, spreadsheetgear

I'm using SpreadSheetGear to create a 3D Pie chart. How do I change the Y-rotation value? I keep getting the image on the left (in Excel the Y-rotation value is 15 degrees) when what I want is the one on the right (in Excel the Y-rotation value is 50 degrees).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

```
SpreadsheetGear.Charts.IChart chart = ...
chart.ChartType = SpreadsheetGear.Charts.ChartType.Pie3D;
chart.Elevation = 50;  // sets the elevation from which a 3D chart is viewed in degrees
```